# Python: Get running methods name from external method

Tags: python, logging

I'm creating a custom log function which needs to get the name of the method running it. How can I get the method's name passed to the log function. For example, this:

```
def log(msg):
    print(f'{runningMethod}: {msg}') # runningMethod is the intended parameter to get passed
    return


def testFunc():
    log("Running")
    return

testFunc()
```

should output this:

> testFunc: Running

It is required that log() only takes that one argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `inspect.currentframe()` and take the previous:

eg:

```
import inspect

def log(msg):
    caller = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    runningMethod = caller.f_code.co_name
    print(f'{runningMethod}: {msg}') # runningMethod is the intended parameter to get passed
    return


def testFunc():
    log("Running")
    return

testFunc()
```